# GeoServer WMS OGC-filter fails with "I don't understand the tag: gml:Polygon"

Tags: geoserver, wms, gml, ogc

I'm trying to construct an OGC filter to pass to a WMS GetMap request to GeoServer but I can't seem to do it. The goal is to show the parts of the layer that intersects with a supplied polygon.

[image]

When I run the query I don't get a result but get this in the server logs:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Attempted to construct illegal filter - I don't understand the tag: gml:Polygon.  HINT: tags are case-sensitive!
```

Any ideas?

The query:

```
http://kar-toffel1.kartena.intra:8080/geoserver/kartena/wms?LAYERS=kartena%3Aosakert-luftkabel&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG%3A2400&FILTER=%3CFilter%20xmlns%3Agml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%22%3E%3CIntersects%3E%3CPropertyName%3Ethe_geom%3C%2FPropertyName%3E%3Cgml%3APolygon%20srsName%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%2Fsrs%2Fepsg.xml%232400%22%3E%3Cgml%3AouterBoundaryIs%3E%3Cgml%3ALinearRing%3E%3Cgml%3Acoordinates%3E1271018%2C6404272%201271210%2C6404272%201271210%2C6404209%201271018%2C6404272%3C%2Fgml%3Acoordinates%3E%3C%2Fgml%3ALinearRing%3E%3C%2Fgml%3AouterBoundaryIs%3E%3C%2Fgml%3APolygon%3E%3C%2FIntersects%3E%3C%2FFilter%3E&CRS=EPSG%3A2400&BBOX=1270899.0723165,6404076.7312769,1271329.8765605,6404348.0392931&WIDTH=524&HEIGHT=330
```

The filter unescaped:

```xml
<Filter xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <Intersection>
        <PropertyName>the_geom</PropertyName>
        <gml:Polygon srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#2400">
            <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                <gml:LinearRing>
                    <gml:coordinates>
                        1271018,6404272 
                        1271210,6404272 
                        1271210,6404209 
                        1271018,6404272
                    </gml:coordinates>
                 </gml:LinearRing>
            </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
        </gml:Polygon>
    </Intersection>
 </Filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter and query look correct.

It appears you've encountered a bug in the QGIS software.  I've reproduced this bug on a newer version also, and reported it to QGIS on their issue tracker: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13065; you are welcome to post on that page to confirm you experience the bug as well.